# Acessar dados do objeto com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> Olá, Boa tarde! Eu tenho um array com alguns objetos dentro, e queria acessar as valores de cada objeto, só que eu consigo acessar o objeto somente se especificar qual posição do array em que está o objeto, tipo assim:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([
    {
      chatId: 1,
      title: "Nome do usuário",
      image:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/01/21/11/avatar-1789663_960_720.png",
      numberPhone: "559198765432",
      status: "Online",
    },
    {
      chatId: 2,
      title: "Nome do usuário",
      image:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/01/21/11/avatar-1789663_960_720.png",
      numberPhone: "559198765432",
      status: "Online",
    },
    {
      chatId: 3,
      title: "Nome do usuário",
      image:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/01/21/11/avatar-1789663_960_720.png",
      numberPhone: "559198765432",
      status: "Offline",
    },
  ]);
```

> Como eu faço para montar um trecho de html com essas informações? Olha como eu estou fazendo:

```
function ListContacts() {
return (
<Container
      className={`chatlistItem ${active ? "active" : ""}`}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <Avatar src={user.image} />
      <BoxRow>
        <Row>
          <Title>{user.title}</Title>
          <DateList>
            <p>12:00</p>
          </DateList>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <LastMessage>
            <p>{user.status}</p>
          </LastMessage>
        </Row>
      </BoxRow>
    </Container>
 )
}
```

> Quero montar uma lista de contatos com os dados de cada objeto, mas só consigo acessar um de cada vez. Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa realizar uma iteração pelo seu array, passando por cada objeto e retornar o que deseja. Então ficaria algo como:

```
return this.user.map((item) => (
    <Container key={item.chatId}>
        {item.title}
    </Container>
));
```

Comment: Valeu, amigo. Acho que funcionou